# Looking forward to follow vs. following

Tags: participles, ing

I was reading this today:

*We look forward to following your progress.*

Am I correct in thinking that it is missing a *be* or that *-ing* should be removed?

So

*We look forward to be following your progress.*

or

*We look forward to follow your progress.*

Interestingly I get the same jarring feeling when reading the examples here
[What's the difference between "I look forward to" and "I'm looking forward to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10144/whats-the-difference-between-i-look-forward-to-and-im-looking-forward-to)

Comment: @Mari-LouA So you mark this as a duplicate because a similar one was asked a few months before 4 years ago? I would think that my "be" makes it not duplicate, although the answer with the gerund does.

Comment: There are more answers, aren't there? In four years this question has got one answer, do you think anyone will actually come along and post a better answer than MT-Head's?

Comment: I was just wondering, that's all

Comment: That is not a duplicate at all in my opinion. My examples are both valid.

Comment: The **accepted** answer disagrees with you. But if you think your question  is still valid, and hasn't been answered properly set up a bounty :)

Comment: Nah - I cannot be bothered. I was just taken aback for a second

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*We look forward to following your progress* is correct; the two proposed corrections are not. "Following your progress" is a [gerund phrase](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm); it acts as a noun in this sentence.