# Can gerund be used after "to"?

Tags: grammaticality

We were taught in school that gerund comes after 'for', while infinitive follows 'to'.

However, I came across this sentence :"Thank you for devoting your time **to** read**ing** my letter"

Whatever research I try to do on the subject, the only results I get are *'ways to thank people for their time'* and *'how to write formal letters'* , but it's the given grammar structure i'm interested in.

So can you please help out?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: In 'I took time to read your letter', 'to' is the infinitive marker. But in 'I devoted time to reading your letter / to a reasonable exercise regime / to the goldfish', 'to' is on the preposition ... transitivising particle continuum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking forward to follow vs. following](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30345/looking-forward-to-follow-vs-following). See also [How the verb becomes a gerund after 'to' eg 'committed to helping you'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197699/how-the-verb-becomes-a-gerund-after-to-e-g-committed-to-helping-you), and other links.

Comment: Now here's an answer that you will be able to understand!: Yes, you can -- the gerund-participial clause "reading my letter" is complement of the preposition "to", and your sentence is fine and grammatical.