# Looking forward

Tags: progressive-aspect, sense-verbs

Recently I've seen a sentence with "looking forward". Could you explain why it contains a progressive aspect. Doesn't this phrase mean a thought process which cannot be seen and thus must be regarded as stative and be used without progressive?

Consider a sentence like

> I am looking forward to repaying your kindness.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the entire sentence and to know something of its context.

Comment: [What's the difference between “I look forward to” and “I'm looking forward to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10144/whats-the-difference-between-i-look-forward-to-and-im-looking-forward-to)

Comment: To me, "Look forward" describes a static continuous state; "looking forward" is more transient. "I'm looking forward to your call, but if someone shows me a LOLcat I'll probably forget about it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of verbs expressing perception, emotion, wishing and thinking that do not normally have a progressive form, and it's reasonable to think that *look forward to* should be among them. In fact, both *I look forward to . . .* and *I am looking forward to . . .* are possible in your example. The progressive form implies a more temporary state and, for that reason, is probably more likely to be used in speech than in writing.